# location - returned from where?

Tags: meaning-in-context, attachment-ambiguity, locative

Consider the following sentences. If John had come from Boston, was it the place Peter arrived at, or the place Peter came from?

> 1. Peter returned from where John had come.
> 2. Peter returned whence John had come.

The online [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/whence?q=whence) says "whence" means "from where" and gives as an example "They returned **whence** they had come." If "whence" equals "from where" and the latter is used instead in the example sentence, the result would be "They returned from where they had come." But I don't know f that paraphrase is appropriate.

It seems that the definition illustrated by the example should be "to the place from which," not "from where."

I suspect there is something wrong with that dictionary.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I've up-voted your question because I think it contains a good amount of detail now that you've edited it. Maybe some people will reconsider their down-votes.

Comment: There is nothing agrammatical here at all. There is, however, a slight usage disconnect between how the questions contain two persons and the dictionary definitions.

Comment: +1 I found this to be a really fascinating question—far more interesting than I had thought it was when I started to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the dictionary definition of *whence*. What's causing confusion is the fascinating way in which ***returned*** *whence* functions.

First, I need to say that your sentence with *whence* initially sounded a bit strange to me.

One of the examples from the Merriam-Webster definition of [**whence**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whence) is:

> //  They returned to the land *whence* they came.

At first I thought it was the *returned to X* in front of *whence* that was missing from your sample sentence that made it odd. But that's not what's happening.

The actual example sentence from your Oxford source is:

> *They returned whence they had come.*

That, too, sounds normal to me. But your version of the sentence is still unusual.

So, what's different about them?

> Oxford: **They** returned whence **they** had come.
>   Yours: **Peter** returned whence **John** had come.

Thinking back on all the times I've heard *hence* used in this way, I've only heard it used *reflexively*.

The actual sentence from Oxford, which sounds normal to me, is reflexive. However, your version is not. But after having sorted this out in my mind, and the more I think about it, the less it's bothering me. (Although it's interesting that you constructed something that I, as a native speaker, would have never thought of doing.)

---

So, let me turn to your actual question.

Here is your first sentence:

> Peter returned from where John had come.

It would be incorrect with *from which*:

> ✘ Peter returned from which John had come.

You are right that *from which* could be used—but only if *to the place* is also used:

> ✔ Peter returned to the place from which John had come.

---

So, if we take your *whence* sentence, there are now two possible paraphrases:

> *Peter returned whence John had come.*
>
> 1. Peter returned from where John had come.
> 2. Peter returned to the place from which John had come.

But even though both are grammatical, they mean different things.

*Return to* does not mean the same thing as *return from*.

When you *return to* a place, you **go** to that place. But when you *return from* a place, you **leave** that place.

To rephrase the two possible sentences:

> 1. Peter **left** (the place) where John had come (from).
> 2. Peter **went** ***to*** the place from which John had come.

---

This leads me to conclude that you're correct:

> *Peter returned whence John had come.*
>
> 1. ✘ Peter returned from where John had come.
> 2. ✔ Peter returned to the place from which John had come.

---

What's interesting here is that you can't *just* replace *whence* with *from where*. You have to look at the syntax of the overall sentence. As such, we end up with this:

```
whence           =  from where  
returned whence  =  returned to the place from which
```